# What is the correct parametrization of the paths of these two particles?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

Imagine two particles -- whose paths I would like to describe
as functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ -- that travel (for $0 \leq t \leq 1$)
in a straight line directly towards each other, say, along the x axis
in 3-space, approaching the origin.  Then, at time, say, $0 < t_1 <
1$, they encounter a sphere of diameter $d$, centered at the origin,
at which point the particles move about the surface of the sphere via
a "3-dimensional sine-wave", like a corkscrew, always maintaining a
distance $d$ from each other as the travel around the sphere.
Finally, at time $t_2 \in (t_1, 1)$, they arrive at the x-axis on the
opposite pole of the sphere from which they entered, and exit the
sphere travelling along the x-axis, continuing along their original
straight line course until $t = 1$.

**Question:**
Could someone please help me write down the functions $a(t)$ and
$b(t)$ that describe the motion of these two particles?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not precise enough to admit a definitive answer, but if this is what you had in mind,
write me and I'll explain.  Alternatively, post to the more appropriate forum [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

     
[image: Curves on sphere]

Comment: Close, but I mean a full twist of the helix all the way around the sphere. (More twist.) What can I say to be more precise? And thank you for the link to Math StackExchange. I did not know it existed. I apologize if I posted it incorrectly. Finally, can you provide a JPG or GIF of the equations themselves?